# Unable to get progress of fcoder 2PDF conversion process running from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line, subprocess

I am trying to fetch progress from the fcoder 2 PDF command line tool output by running it from a Python subprocess. I have successfully captured other lines but not the last 2 lines that show progress. This problem is related to subprocess stdout capturing.

My code is

```py
import subprocess

# Define the command to run
command = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\2PDF\2PDF.exe","-src", r"C:\Users\Rajkumar\Desktop\a\a2.docx" ,"-dst", r"C:\Users\Rajkumar\Desktop" ,"-options", "mswildc:no" ,"-pdf", "ocr:yes", "ocr_lang:English"]

# Use subprocess to run the command and capture the output
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

# Read and print the output while the process is running
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
```

My output is

```
2PDF, Version 2.0, (c) fCoder SIA 2022

---------------------------------------------------------------

Loading files list, please wait...

1 of 1. "C:\Users\Rajkumar\Desktop\a\a2.docx" -> Pdf
...........
Ok

All files converted successfully
```

The following gif shows the progress I want to capture.

[image]

**Edit**

After digging, I found how to capture if a Python script uses  as process that prints progress in one line.
In the following gif **demo7.py** acts as child process to retrieve data in **demo8.py**.

Code for **demo7.py**

```
import time
import sys
num=1
for i in range(11):
    text="#"*i+"."*(10-i)
    print(f"[{text}] {i*10}%",end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Code for **demo8.py**

```
import subprocess,os
command=["python",r"E:\PythonDIR\PdfUtil\demo7.py"]
# Set PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = '1'
# Run demo7.py using subprocess with line buffering
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           universal_newlines=True, env=env)
# Continuously read and print the live output
while True:
    output=process.stdout.readline()
    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    print(output ,end='')
```

Individual output of both scripts can be seen below.
[image]

Similary way we need to crack solution using core level api of windows may be using **ctypes** module for external executable(.exe) file like 2PDF.

Comment: Why there can't be any progress!! , look the gif it  clearly shows progress .And I am using a small word file for conversion that why it shows direct 0 to 100 but for a long file it shows progress clearly. My question is how to catch those line that are printed as progress and in same line not in new lines.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? I can't get your point. If it is printing on cmd of Windows then why can't we capture that output with python sub-process. The problem is that progress line(2 lines that are updated in same line.) . Can you give any code?

Comment: I got your point , Let's just forget about fcoder , we just focus on how to capture lines of a process that prints different values in same line , it could be any process. I think it is challenging cause that does not uses newlines

Comment: i dont think it is related to graphics frame buffer . i have updated my code please check.

Comment: Line buffering works for only python program by setting an environment variable but It is not working with the any executable (**.exe**) file, so the solution lies in creating a console output redirection said in https://github.com/buck54321/PipeStuffer . It is a update of Windows 10 issue of **RTconsole**. It will be really helpful if you make a exe that can be used as command line tool or wrap them using python cause I don't know much about c++ .

Comment: did you check with pipestuffer or that old RTconsole ? Cause the old one has bugs with windows 10.

Comment: thats why you got the incomplete output. it will be helpful if you compile and check new one and answer here. You dont need it doesnt mean no one will need it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies **Real-Time Console Output Redirection** .But my answer is incomplete i have  just converted the code to python but unable to use logic for reading/parsing the output. I need help for that.

**1. Crete a pipe in python and read continuosly from it**

```
import ctypes,time
from ctypes import wintypes

# Define the required constants and structures
PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX = 0x00000003
PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE = 0x00000004
PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE = 0x00000002
PIPE_WAIT = 0x00000000
PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES = 255
BUFSIZE = 512
NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT = 0x00000000
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nLength", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("lpSecurityDescriptor", wintypes.LPVOID),
                ("bInheritHandle", wintypes.BOOL)]

# Create a named pipe
def create_named_pipe(pipe_name):
    sa = SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
    sa.nLength = ctypes.sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = None
    sa.bInheritHandle = True
    pipe_handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateNamedPipeW(
        pipe_name,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        BUFSIZE,
        BUFSIZE,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        ctypes.byref(sa)
    )
    if pipe_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        print("Failed to create named pipe")
        return None
    else:
        print("Named pipe created successfully")
        return pipe_handle

# Example usage

def read_from_pipe(pipe_handle):
    # time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUFSIZE)
        bytes_read = wintypes.DWORD()

        success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadFile(
            pipe_handle,
            buffer,
            BUFSIZE,
            ctypes.byref(bytes_read),
            None
        )
        #print(success)
        if not success :
            #print("Failed to read from the pipe or no data available.")
            
            error_code = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
            #print("err-",error_code)
            if error_code==536 or error_code==234:
                
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            else:
                break

        data = buffer.raw[:bytes_read.value]

        print(f"Received data: {data.decode('utf-8')}",end="")
        print("\n\nDone\n\n")
while True:
    pipe_name = r'\\.\pipe\raj' # pipe name is "raj"
    pipe_handle = create_named_pipe(pipe_name)

    read_from_pipe(pipe_handle)
```

**2. Convertion of C++ code into Python that posted in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection and https://github.com/buck54321/PipeStuffer[2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection)**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import sys
import time



class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

origin = COORD(0, 0)

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('nLength', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('lpSecurityDescriptor', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('bInheritHandle', wintypes.BOOL)
    ]
class STARTUPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cb", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("lpReserved", wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ("lpDesktop", wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ("lpTitle", wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ("dwX", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwY", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwXSize", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwYSize", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwXCountChars", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwYCountChars", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwFillAttribute", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwFlags", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("wShowWindow", wintypes.WORD),
                ("cbReserved2", wintypes.WORD),
                ("lpReserved2", wintypes.LPBYTE),
                ("hStdInput", wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("hStdOutput", wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("hStdError", wintypes.HANDLE)]


class PROCESS_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("hProcess", wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("hThread", wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("dwProcessId", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwThreadId", wintypes.DWORD)]

# Define the CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO structure
class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwSize", COORD),  # Size of the console screen buffer
        ("dwCursorPosition", COORD),  # Cursor position
        ("wAttributes", wintypes.WORD),  # Screen buffer attributes
        ("srWindow", wintypes.SMALL_RECT),  # Window rectangle
        ("dwMaximumWindowSize", COORD),  # Maximum window size
    ]




STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080


def main():
    
    dwDummy = ctypes.c_ulong()

    # Parse command line: skip to RTconsole's arguments
   
    command_line=r"C:\Users\Rajkumar\Downloads\Compressed\RTconsoleDemo\RTconsoleDemo\Release\DemoConsole.exe"
    #path to any console based application
    # Prepare the console window & inherited screen buffer
    
    pipe_name = r"\\.\pipe\raj"

    named_pipe = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateFileW(
        pipe_name, 0x40000000, 0, None, 3, 0, None
    )
    if named_pipe == -1:
        error_code = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
        print(f"Failed to create/open named pipe. Error code: {error_code}")
        return
    sa = SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(
        ctypes.sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), None, True
    )
    hConsole = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
        0x80000000 | 0x40000000, 1 | 2, ctypes.byref(sa), 1, None
    )


    ctypes.windll.kernel32.FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(
        hConsole, b'\0', 0x7fffffff, COORD(0, 0), ctypes.byref(dwDummy)

    )

    if not ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole):
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hConsole)
        return 1
    
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetStdHandle(-11, hConsole)

    # Start the subprocess
    pi = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
    si = STARTUPINFO()
    si.cb = ctypes.sizeof(si)
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK
    # si.hStdOutput = hConsole
    if not ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateProcessA(
        None,  # ApplicationName
        ctypes.create_string_buffer(command_line.encode()),  # CommandLine
        None,  # ProcessAttributes
        None,  # ThreadAttributes
        True,  # InheritHandles
        0,  # CreationFlags
        None,  # Environment
        None,  # CurrentDirectory
        ctypes.byref(si),
        ctypes.byref(pi)
    ):
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hConsole)
        return -2
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(pi.hThread)

    last_pos = COORD(0, 0)
    csbi = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()
    exit_now = False
    while not exit_now:
        if ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 0) != 0x102:
            exit_now = True  # Exit after this last iteration

        # Get screen buffer state
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, ctypes.byref(csbi))
        line_width = csbi.dwSize.X

        if csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y == last_pos.Y and  csbi.dwCursorPosition.X == last_pos.X:
            
            time.sleep(0.05)
            
        else:
            count = (csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y - last_pos.Y) * line_width + csbi.dwCursorPosition.X - last_pos.X
            # Read newly output characters starting from the last cursor position
            buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(count)
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA(hConsole, buffer, count, last_pos, ctypes.byref(dwDummy))
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(hConsole,b"\0", count, last_pos, ctypes.byref(dwDummy))
            last_pos = csbi.dwCursorPosition
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, ctypes.byref(csbi))
            if (csbi.dwCursorPosition.X == last_pos.X) and (csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y == last_pos.Y):
                # Text cursor did not move since this treatment, hurry to reset it to home
                ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, origin)
                last_pos = origin
            

            '''Need help to Parse output and send to PIPE here
            For Example 
            bytes_written = wintypes.DWORD()
            success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteFile(
                    named_pipe,
                    buffer.value,
                    len(buffer.value),
                    ctypes.byref(bytes_written),
                    None
                )
            '''
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hConsole)

    # Release subprocess handle
    exit_code = ctypes.c_ulong()
    if not ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, ctypes.byref(exit_code)):
        exit_code.value = -3
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)
    return exit_code.value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```